# Nodejs Mongodb verify value on schema array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to know how I can verify if a value is in an array of a different value in the schema. Have a look at this example:

```
const progressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    possible_statuses: {
        type: Array
    },
    first_status: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

And a POST (insert) example of this would be:

```
{
    possible_statuses: ['Untouched', 'In Progress', 'Complete'],
    first_status: 'Untouched'
}
```

But a PUT (update) on the above item using this:

```
{
    id: hwad0912he109sj(whatever),
    first_status: 'Recalled'
}
```

Should throw an error like: `Invalid first_status`

Could someone please give me an example of how this would work. I would assume you would need to use something like `progressSchema.pre('save'...`

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose has an enum property for this usecase. See the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) and example below:

```
const progressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    possible_statuses: {
        type: Array
    },
    first_status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Untouched', 'In Progress', 'Complete']
    }
});
```

Comment: No but this array is dynamic. In every progress entry it will look different. So you can't hardcode it like this...but thank you for teaching me this though!

Comment: In that case, i would add the enums to the schema containing all possible values (for correctness validation), and then use something like https://github.com/hapijs/joi at the api controller level to do the business logic validation.

Comment: I cannot predict what all the possible values would be. It is purely dynamic. Yeah you can sort out numbers & non-alphabetic characters, but that is not solving my issue with them linking to the relatives